# Am unable to remove messages that are nested within $_SESSION array using a foreach loop, unset

Tags: php, arrays, session

For some reason my code below is not completely working. i’ve been unable to unset the array element. otherwise, the code seems to works. i’m using echo javascript alert to confirm the elements exist in the array. Maybe the problem has to do with the nature of $_SESSION vars?

The array is this,

```
Array
(
    [commerce_cart_orders] => Array
    (
        [0] => 33
    )

[messages] => Array
    (
        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => Notice: Use of undefined constant actions - assumed 'actions' in mytheme_form_alter() …..
                [1] => Notice: Use of undefined constant submit - assumed 'submit' in mytheme_form_alter() ….
                [2] => Notice: Use of undefined constant actions - assumed 'actions' in mytheme_form_alter() ….
                [3] => Notice: Use of undefined constant submit - assumed 'submit' in mytheme_form_alter() ….
```

My code so far is this,

```
$toRemoveOne = "Notice: Use of undefined constant actions - assumed 'actions' in ";
$toRemoveTwo = "Notice: Use of undefined constant submit - assumed 'submit' ";
foreach ($_SESSION['messages']['error'] as $val) {
    if((strpos($val, $toRemoveOne) == true) || (strpos($val, $toRemoveTwo) == true)){
    echo '<script>alert("it exists")</script>';
     //unset($_SESSION['messages']['error'][$val]);
    unset($val);
}
```

but then i print out the $_SESSION vars and they are still there.
What am i doing wrong here? thanks!

Comment: add `&`  before val - `foreach ($_SESSION['messages']['error'] as &$val)`

Comment: @splash58 I'd avoid `&` if you can. It can produce [weird results](http://codepad.org/gyfLepCO).

Comment: Sorry, i wrong.  with `&` you can modify item, but not unset

Answer (score 0):

RTM: http://php.net/strpos

It can return either an integer position of the matched string, or boolean false. It'll never return `true`. `== true` will simply be treated as `== 1`, and since your matched string occurs right at position `0`, you're doing `0 == 1` and the if() never triggers.

You want:

```
if (strpos(...) !== false)
                ^^^
```

instead.

As well, `$val` in your foreach() is a COPY of the value in the array. You're unsetting that temporary copy, not the value that's actually in the array. you need to `unset($yourarray[$key])` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['messages']['error'] as $key => $val) {
   if((strpos($val, $toRemoveOne) == true) || (strpos($val, $toRemoveTwo) == true)){
    echo '<script>alert("it exists")</script>';
      //unset($_SESSION['messages']['error'][$val]);
    unset($_SESSION[$key]);
}
```

$val is passed by value not by reference